# Assigning and accessing pointer to string within struct

Tags: c, pointers, c99, struct, memcpy

I'm trying to store a string in an array contained within a struct, and access it, but I'm having a hard time. The struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct {
    void **storage;
    int numStorage;
} Box;
```

Box is initialized as such:

```
    b->numStorage = 1000000; // Or set more intelligently
    Box *b = malloc(sizeof(Box));
    // Create an array of pointers
    b->storage = calloc(b->numStorage,sizeof(void *));
```

In order to set the string, I use this function:

```
void SetString(Box *b, int offset, const char * key)
{
    // This may seem redundant but is necessary
    // I know I could do strcpy, but made the following alternate
    // this isn't the issue
    char * keyValue = malloc(strlen(key) + 1);
    memcpy(keyValue, key, strlen(key) + 1);

    // Assign keyValue to the offset pointer
    b->storage[offset*sizeof(void *)] = &keyValue;

    // Check if it works
    char ** ptr = b->storage[offset*sizeof(void *)];

    // It does
    printf("Hashcode %d, data contained %s\n", offset, *ptr);

}
```

The problem lies when I try to retrieve it again, with the exact same offset:

```
// Return pointer to string
void *GetString(const Box *b, int offset, const char *key)

    char ** ptr = b->storage[offset*sizeof(void *)];
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        printf("Data should be %s\n", *ptr);
        return *ptr;
    } else {
     return NULL;
    }
```

The returned pointer is gibberish. What could be amiss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to specify the actual memory offset when accessing arrays. Simply give it the index and you will get the correct element.

So, in your third code block:

```
b->storage[offset] = keyValue;
```

And in your fourth:

```
char *ptr = b->storage[offset];
if (ptr != NULL) {
    printf("Data should be %s\n", ptr);
    return ptr;
} else {
 return NULL;
}
```

Also, in the second block of code, has `b->numStorage` already been set?

Answer (score 2):

```
b->storage[offset*sizeof(void *)] = &keyValue;
```

This stores the address of the local variable `keyValue` in the array.  Once the function completes, this address becomes invalid.  I think you want:

```
b->storage[offset*sizeof(void *)] = keyValue;
```

and then make the corresponding change while retrieving.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't this:

```
b->storage[offset*sizeof(void *)] = &keyValue
```

set storage[offset*sizeof(void*)] to point to the address of the local variable keyValue? i.e. no longer valid after function returns